# Don't execute certain code while running a JUnit Test in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, junit

I'm using Eclipse and JUnit 4 while developing an application within a tomcat container. The container manages the connection to our Oracle database.

While testing with JUnit i've got the following problem: In the constructor of the test subject there is something like this:

```
public Subject() {
    // stuff
    FancySingleton.getInstance().getFancy("stuff");
}
```

Unfortunately the method `getFancy()` tries to execute a Query which it can't because JUnit does not run within the tomcat container and ends up in an endless loop.

My first idea was to out-commend the code. At second thought it appeared to be a bad idea. I could forget to remove the comments before committing.

My second idea was to highlight the code for eclipse so that it doesn't execute it while running a JUnit test. But it requires eclipse to support such a method.

At last i thought of something like preprocessor directives.

What is your idea? Just passing in a boolean to the constructor is imho not a clean way of dealing with such a circumstance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd either mock FancySingleton, or you'd do it right and inject an implementation.

Comment: I would also add that calling a method that executes a Query in a constructor makes the class hard to test, and can make code that uses the class even harder to test.

Comment: Thank you for the replies. This is a very old application and we try to introduce unit tests in a step by step progress. In normal service, the singleton would almost never fire a query at this point because it's a cache that is updated by a job at night on a daily basis. But, as you said, testing sth. which fires automatically a query is a pain in the... to test.